# Do these phrases work well for a Canadian French audience?

Tags: traduction, québec

I'm attempting to translate some short phrases into French for a Canadian French-speaking audience. I came up with the following off the top of my head (given my intermediate facility with French):

Easier than ever to use = Plus facile à utiliser que jamais; Traffic Alerts = Alertes trafic; Safe Driving Mode = Mode de conduite sécuritaire; New & Improved = Nouveau et amélioré; OneTouch Favorites = OneTouch Favoris

Are all of these phrases comprehensible and native-sounding to a Canadian French speaker?

Comment: Although supplying your own attempts is a good start, please keep in mind that this is not a translation/proofreading service but a Q&A site where people search by topic to learn more about particular vocabulary and grammar. Thus, there are a bunch of issues in this one question. Someone might tackle this despite that site purpose, but ideally you would make separate threads, such as "OneTouch Favoris: Unsure if *favoris* is the right word", with a quick note on your decision and resource(s), and why you're not sure after having consulted those. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For my part, I whould say that most of them sound right to a french canadian (me ;) ) Maybe just add this would be more natural:

> Alertes de trafic

And I'm not sure about this one could you give us a little more context to help you find the best way to say it?

> OneTouch Favorites = OneTouch Favoris